# Second mixed weak derivatives of function not absolutely continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u,v:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ functions not absolutely continuous in $[0,1]$ but integrable in $(0,1)$. Let $w:(0,1)\times(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$
(x,y)\mapsto u(x)+v(y)
$$
then $w$ is locally integrable and don't have first order weak derivates. Prove that $w$ has second mixed weak derivates.

I'm trying by definition but stuck in

$$
\int w \partial^{(1,1)} \phi  = \int u \partial^{(1,1)} \phi + \int v \partial^{(1,1)} \phi
$$
Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Wouldn't $\partial^{(0, 1)} u = 0$ and $\partial^{1, 0} v=0$ then?